# How to remove the black border displaying around the android Viewpager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout

I have introduced Viewpager with 3 fragments on an activity, but I am getting that black border around the layout. How can I remove that?

[image]

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Can you post the code for the drawable set as `android:background` for `view_pager`?

Answer (score 1):

The black border could be a result of Viewpager being inside another view, you can try setting the Viewpager width to match parent.

You can also try setting the "border" attribute for Viewpager to none.

Comment: already I tried with that , not working out. :(

Comment: It looks like you're designing the activity with the emulator, if so then that's how the screen edges would look like

Comment: No I am not designing using the emulator.